# Why am I getting exc_bad_access errors for objectAtIndex in my floodfill algorithm

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exc-bad-access, flood-fill

I have a flood fill function:

```
-(void) fillArea :(int) fillNum x:(int) xSpot y:(int) ySpot
{
    int gridValue = 1;
    int gridCount = [theGrid count];
    [[theGrid objectAtIndex:(xSpot+ySpot*120)] getValue:&gridValue];

    if (gridValue != 0) {
        return;
    }
    [theGrid replaceObjectAtIndex:(xSpot + ySpot*120) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:fillNum]];
    [self fillArea:fillNum x:(xSpot+1) y:(ySpot)];
    [self fillArea:fillNum x:(xSpot+1) y:(ySpot-1)];
    [self fillArea:fillNum x:(xSpot)   y:(ySpot-1)];
    [self fillArea:fillNum x:(xSpot-1) y:(ySpot-1)];
    [self fillArea:fillNum x:(xSpot-1) y:(ySpot)];
    [self fillArea:fillNum x:(xSpot-1) y:(ySpot+1)];
    [self fillArea:fillNum x:(xSpot)   y:(ySpot+1)];
    [self fillArea:fillNum x:(xSpot+1) y:(ySpot+1)];

    return;
}
```

`theGrid` is an `NSMutableArray` of ints (either a `0` or a `1`).  It is just a **1D array** that simulates a **2D array** by multiplying the `ySpot` by `120` (the width of my grid).  I checked the `gridCount` and it is equal to `9600`.

However, I get an `exc_bad_access` at `[[theGrid objectAtIndex:(xSpot+ySpot*120)] getValue:&gridValue]`.  I check my `xSpot` and `ySpot` when this happens and I know that `(xSpot+ySpot*120) < 9600` every time.  So I know it's not that I'm trying to access an object who's index is outside my array.

Futhermore, in my tick function I ran the code:

```
int gVal = 1;
int gIndex = 0;
while (gIndex < [theGrid count]) {
    [[theGrid objectAtIndex:gIndex] getValue:&gVal];
    gIndex += 1;
}
```

I did not get an `exc_bad_access` error.  Please help me figure out why I'm getting an `exc_bad_access` error.

EDIT:

I split [[theGrid objectAtIndex:(xSpot+ySpot*120)] getValue:&gridValue]; into:

```
id object = [theGrid objectAtIndex:(xSpot+ySpot*widthInGridSize)];
gridValue = [object intValue];
```

I still get exc_bad_access and it says it is on the line:
    gridValue = [object intValue];

So I assume this means object has already been released?  I don't understand how that's possible.  I thought ints didn't need to be retained in any way since they're just ints.  Also I thought adding an object to an array automatically retained it so why would my int get released.

In the debug section the value of object is said equal: (_NSCFNumber *) 0x005aec80 (int) 0

Comment: I think if you're out of bounds, you'd get an out-of-bounds exception; not a bad access.  I suspect either theGrid or the object you're pulling out of it is bogus (already released).  Break that into multiple lines to confirm; and turn on "zombies" in your debug settings.

Comment: I split it up into two lines and found the error is in gridValue = [object intValue];   I also enabled Zombies in the diagnostics tab of my scheme.  Not sure how to actually check for zombies though.

Comment: When zombies are enabled, the OS set your pointer to an NSZombie object instead of leaving the 'dangling' pointer.  Later, if you try to access the object after it's been released, you'll get a nice runtime error.  (ie, you crash faster.)  If this solved your issue, let me know and I'll move my comment to the answer box.

Comment: That solved my issue.  Thank you so much.  I had stupidly added an object to my theGrid array, earlier in my code, which wasn't an integer and in fact had been released.  Doing NSZombie helped my find the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments - this isn't actually an out of bounds issue, but rather the object you're pulling out of 'theGrid' is bogus (already released). Break that into multiple lines to confirm; and turn on "zombies" in your debug settings.  Cheers!